# Match multiple patterns in a string in R

Tags: r, string

I'm looking for a way in R to match multiple patterns in a string. For example:

```
test <- c("abcdefg", "defabc", "abcghdeft" , "abegrabc", "ghdefab", "dabce rdeft", "dedef abceg")
```

I want to look for 2 exact patterns "abc" and "def" in the string, and return `TRUE` if both of them are in the string regardless of position and order. So based on that the result would be:

```
TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

I can't seem to find the AND operator in regex like the OR operator `|`, I've tried other combinations like `abc.*def|def.*abc` but they didn't work.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: you can put your pattern inside `str_detect` from stringr package: `stringr::str_detect(test, "abc.*def|def.*abc")` and you will get your desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grepl`

```
grepl("abc.*def|def.*abc", test)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```